# C# add extent report screenshot into HTML report

Tags: c#, extentreports

So i have `NUnit` tests and `Extent Report` HTML report. After each test execution, in case of failure i want to show the `screenshot` inside my `HTML` report.

So this is what i have tried:

After each test execution, in case of test failure:

```
[TearDown]
public void AfterEachTest()
{
    var status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
    if (status == TestStatus.Failed)
    {
        string path = Browser.CaptureScreeshot();
        BaseReport.ExtentTest.Log(Status.Fail, "Test fail");
        BaseReport.ExtentTest.AddScreenCaptureFromPath(path);
    }
}
```

As you can see `string path = Browser.CaptureScreeshot()` returns my `.png` screenshot, this path is valid and exist but inside the `report` this look like that:

[image]

Why my `picture` is not recognized ?

I also tried `AddScreenCaptureFromBase64String` instead of `AddScreenCaptureFromPathbut` even that didn't work.

Comment: You must save the image either using an absolute path, or relative to the report. Relative paths are highly recommended unless the reports are to be viewed only on one machine.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with this:

```
    //To take screenshot
    Screenshot file = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();

    //To save screenshot
    file.SaveAsFile(parentDirName + "\\Screenshots\\" + SSName + ".png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

    //To log screenshot
    testlog.Info("Details", MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromPath( "\\Screenshots\\" + SSName + ".png").Build());
```